# How to confirm if a branch was merged via SQL?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, branching-and-merging

Does anyone know how to confirm if a branch was merged via SQL query?  In the long run, I want to create an on demand SSRS report so this can be reviewed after a series of releases have been deployed.  I know that there are specific Command bit values taken from tbl_Version (I did this to identify a renamed branch) but I haven't been able to identify the bit values that identify a branch if it was merged.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

**These tables are not supported for reporting.** Any solution you build should use the TFS Object Model to load the data into the warehouse. Or use the client object model directly to retrieve the data.

What you're trying to do is really hard since the data isn't stored in the warehouse. You can query merge data by calling the [`VersionControlServer.QueryMerges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138969%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) method or by going through each Changeset individually after calling [`VersionControlServer.QueryHistory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138960%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Building a DatawarehouseAdapter is harder still, since there is little documentation available and since you should have a deep knowledge of both the TFS Object Model, the Warehouse structure and Analysis Server in general. There is a ranger project underway to provide additional guidance on this subject, but until that's done you will find mostly just a scattered few blogposts and a very bad example.

You might be able to find good pointers towards building something outside of the scope of Reporting Server in open source projects, such as the [TfsChangeLog](http://tfschangelog.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/19920#180640) project or the [Community TFS Build Manager](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/83023#1631565).

Comment: I'd really like to use SSRS to find a solution, even if it is unsupported. If no one can help, I can try the Client Object Model.  I downloaded/installed it and I can't figure out how to use it.  Any pointers?

Comment: As suggestion to avoid forcing your way into SQL, RS can work with other types of datasources - for example xml on website or embeding .NET assembly with the code required to return data your intrested from tfs. The website option is in my opinion the simplest one especialy if you have access to tfs server itself.